# Adding sub domain website

Tags: domain

I recently purchased a VPS hosting and everything went well.

I tried to set a blog for my site as follows :

blog.trimhold.com

I created in DNS manager a Cname that points to : www.trimhold.com/blog .

Where the blog website is located.

but It isn't working for some reason.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System), as the name says, deals with [Domain Names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name), not URLs. You can't put a path (like /blog) in a [CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cname).

You should put an A record for blog.whatever.com that points to the IP address of your server, and configure an HTTP [Virtual Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) on the server.

Comment: Ok, I just created a Host(A) record in my DNS Manager.

Comment: My blog is hosted under wwwroot/blog.

Comment: how can I link now : blog.trimhold.com to www.trimhold.con/blog ?